# How does Reordering removes backward Loop-Carried-Dependence

Tags: c, loops, parallel-processing, dependencies, openmp

Given the following code there is a backwards dependency.

```c
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  (S1): d[i] = a[i-1] * d[i];
  (S2): a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
}
```

My question is how to define / identify these backwards dependencies. As I can't really find a scheme for myself to do this.

This is how I'm currently tackling the issue:
In this example `S1 has a anti-dependency on S2` as S1 first reads and S2 writes to the variable.

Further we learned to create a direction vector:

```
Iteration: read:  write
v1:
S1(9)      a[8]   
S2(9)      -      a[9]

v2:
S1(10)     a[9]   -
S2(10)     -      a[10]
```

Which would result in direction vecor D_v: `D_v = v2 - v1 = (i - 1) - i = -1 = >`

Now the solution is to reorder the statements, which is possible as S1 and S2 have no dependencies within the loop.

```c
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  (S1): a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
  (S2): d[i] = a[i-1] * d[i];
}
```

Which would result in `S1 has a true-dependency on S2` as S1 first writes and S2 reads the variable.
If I repeat to create the direction vector:

```
Iteration: read:  write
v1:
S1(9)      -      a[9]
S2(9)      a[8]   -

v2:
S1(10)     -      a[10]
S2(10)     a[9]   -
```

Which would now result in the direction vector `D_v: D_v = v2 - v1 = (i + 1) - i = +1 = <`

The direction vector now is `< instead of > (or +1 instead of -1)`

But I just don't see the connection between direction vector and backwards dependency? Is this purly on `< or > ?`? Can someone clarify how to identify backward dependencies and why exactly the reordering is no backwards dependency anymore (At best with this example)?
As from my point of view we still depend on the last iteration of the loop. But my resources (lecture) says that this is not an backwards dependency anymore and we could vectorize the loop.

Comment: `a[i]` does not depend on `d`, so you can reorder the two statements. If you now re-index S2 to read `d[i+1] = a[i] * d[i+1]`, it becomes trivial to vectorise as you can simply expand `a[i]` and rewrite S2 as `d[i+1] = (b[i] + c[i]) * d[i+1]` or reuse the result of the previous vector operation implementing S1.

Comment: @HristoIliev your explaination seems reasonable to me. But could you explain that with the concepts of backwards loop carried dependencies ?
As my main point of the question is not how the vectorization works. It is more about how the concepts of the distance vector is connected to backwards carried dependencies.

Comment: Can you, please, share this lecture so we can understand your point of view on these terms, such as "backwards dependency" ? I have to agree with @Hristo Iliev, but in order to give a detailed answer on that, you have to provide us your source of info, so we can stay on the same page and communicate clearly

Comment: I'm not familiar with this "direction vector" terminology and simply gave you my reasoning as to why there is no dependency after reordering the statements.

Comment: Just a few links. The cs.ucsb is an equivalent lecture with the terms introduced.

https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~yufeiding/cs293s/slides/293S_09_Parallelism_data_dependence.pdf

https://cnx.org/contents/u4IVVH92@5.2:Qv3tWJ-B@3/Loop-Carried-Dependencies

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_dependence_analysis

Comment: I think you made a mistake when creating the second table for the iterations. For iteration 9 S1 writes to `a[9]` and S2 reads from `a[8]`. This is basically the same as the first table and should result in the same direction vector, from my limited understanding.